# Spring Security и аннотация доступа к контроллеру

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Имеется контроллер, в котором все методы, кроме одного, доступны только администратору

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = RestaurantController.REST_URL, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public class RestaurantController {
    //controllerbody
}
```

Можно ли разрешить доступ к одному из методов обычному пользователю, не убирая данную аннотацию об администраторе при объявлении класса?
Не хотелось бы дублировать аннотацию над 10-ю методами без добавления ее лишь над одним методом

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поставить над тем методом, к которому хотите дать доступ пользователю

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or hasAuthority('USER')")
```